# How to increase the number in a file by 1 if the starting number is 000 using bash?

Tags: bash, numbers, counting

**GNU bash, version 4.4.20

Ubuntu 18.04.5**

I need to increment a number in a file by 1 in a loop. The number has to satisfy 3 digits.

Example:

```
001 + 1 = 002
002 + 1 = 003
003 + 1 = 004
004 + 1 = 005
005 + 1 = 006
006 + 1 = 007
007 + 1 = 008
008 + 1 = 009
009 + 1 = 010
010 + 1 = 011
```

I have been adding a 1 to the number in a file after each loop. I then count the characters in the file and then add zeros before the number to satisfy the 3 character number requirement like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

nFile="counter.txt"

if [ ! -e "$nFile" ]; then
    echo "1" > "$nFile"
    echo "Number is 001"
else
    n=$(cat "$nFile")
    m=$(( n + 1 ))
    echo "$m" > "$nFile"
    cCount=$(wc -c "$nFile" | awk '{ print $1 }')
    
    if [ "$cCount" = "2" ]; then
        echo "Number is 00${m} ..."
    elif [ "$cCount" = "3" ]; then
        echo "Number is 0${m} ..."
    fi
fi
```

The above works fine and satisfies Mr. `shellcheck` . Each time the loop runs, the number is correctly printed like so:

```
Number is 001 ...
Number is 002 ...
Number is 003 ...
Number is 004 ...
Number is 005 ...
Number is 006 ...
Number is 007 ...
Number is 008 ...
Number is 009 ...
Number is 010 ...
Number is 011 ...
Number is 012 ...
```

I know there has to be a cleaner way to handle this.

Comment: You want to edit the content of a file or rename the files?

Comment: You only seem to allow numbers from 1 to 99 although your schema seems to allow 3 digits. You have several race conditions if two or more programs run your code at the same time.

Comment: @jhnc My original post was a mess. I rewrote it.

Comment: you can force leading zeros with `printf "%03d" "$n"` but ensure `n` is an integer and in range (don't store the numbers with leading zeros or you'll get base errors)

Comment: @jhnc Can you explain this a little?

Comment: @Cyrus - It doesn't explain how to accept a comment as an answer though.

Comment: @jhnc Can you write up your comment so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: I rolled back your edit; your question should remain strictly a question. If you want to post an answer yourself, you are welcome to; your old text will still be visible in the question's [revision history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68061101/revisions) If you want to abstain from receiving reputation from an answer you got from someone else, you can (obscurely!) mark it "community wiki".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increment an integer stored in bash variable `x` you can do something like `((x=x+1))` or `((++x))`.

However if the number can have leading zeros, then you have to be more careful:

```
x=8
echo $((++x))        # okay, prints 9

x=008
echo $((++x))        # fails with error message

declare -i x=10#008  # force base 10
echo $((++x))        # okay, prints 9
```

---

To format an integer `y` into a fixed width of 3 digits, with leading zeros, you can use:

```
printf '%03d' "$y"
```

You just need to be sure that `y`:

- is an integer,
- doesn't have leading zeros (so bash doesn't treat it as octal), and
- is not 999 (which will overflow to `1000`)

---

If you are storing your state permanently in a file outside the process, then you need to be careful not to run multiple copies of your code at the same time. If you do, because your read/modify/write procedure is not atomic, the state could become corrupted.

You can prevent this problem by using file-locking. Per the `flock` manpage, you could prefix your code with something like:

```
[ "${FLOCKER}" != "$0" ] && exec env FLOCKER="$0" flock -en "$0" "$0" "$@" || :
```

---

Putting all that together gives something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

nFile="counter.txt"

[[ $FLOCKER != $nFile ]] && \
exec env FLOCKER="$nFile" flock -e "$nFile" "$0" "$@" || :

# if we tell flock to use $nFile as its lockfile,
# it will create it (empty) if it doesn't already exist
# so we don't need to test for its existence here
read n <"$nFile"

# force input to be treated as base 10
# n is treated as being 0 if empty
# format incremented value with leading zeros and store into m
printf -v m '%03d' $(( 10#$n + 1 ))

echo "Number is $m ..."
echo $m >"$nFile"
```

Depending on how you want to use the numbers, it may be better to re-factor your program so that locking only occurs around the so-called "critical section", and not around the entire program as here.

Answer (score 1):

This might do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

i=1
file_name=somejazz.txt

while printf -v num '%03d' "$i" && [[ -e "$num-$file_name" ]]; do
  ((i++))
done

> "$num-$file_name"
```

---

Creates a file named `001-somejazz.txt` if it does not exists or increments the `1` if it does and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a cool string increment algorithm. So if `000` is in the file `n.txt`, this perl 1-liner changes it to `001` and continues to increment by 1 each time it's executed.

```
perl -i -e '$n=<>;chomp($n);$n++;print("$n\n")' n.txt
```

Perl is available on all linux installs. Since you are using `awk` anyway, might as well use perl for something it's well-suited to do.